# How to use AdMob?

Tags: android

Everything I have tried to do with AdMob has completely failed and I can't quite seem to figure out why. If I try to make the Activity that Google provides as my main activity, the app crashes. If I make it its own class. the ads simply show up, and I don't even know how to correctly make a XML for AdMob. Heres my AdMob Activity if you want to take a look:

```
package com.dogger20011.mcpemodlocater;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.widget.LinearLayout;

/**
 * A simple {@link Activity} that embeds an AdView.
*/
public class AdMob extends Activity {
/** The view to show the ad. */
private AdView adView;

/* Your ad unit id. Replace with your actual ad unit id. */
private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "INSERT_YOUR_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main_page);

// Create an ad.
adView = new AdView(this);
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

// Add the AdView to the view hierarchy. The view will have no size
// until the ad is loaded.
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
layout.addView(adView);

// Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
// get test ads on a physical device.
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
    .addTestDevice("INSERT_YOUR_HASHED_DEVICE_ID_HERE")
    .build();

// Start loading the ad in the background.
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
super.onResume();
if (adView != null) {
  adView.resume();
}
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
if (adView != null) {
  adView.pause();
}
super.onPause();
}

/** Called before the activity is destroyed. */
@Override
 public void onDestroy() {
// Destroy the AdView.
if (adView != null) {
  adView.destroy();
}
super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I Followed This tuorial to integrate ADMOB in my app

[Admob Integration](http://androidcodexamples.blogspot.in/2013/02/integrating-google-ads-from-admob-in.html)

MY Xml code look like this

```
<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/ad"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       ads:adSize="BANNER"
                       ads:adUnitId="xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xx"
                       ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR,TEST_DEVICE_ID_GOES_HERE"
                       ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
                      />
```

It worked for me perfectly

Comment: When I have that XML it crashes my app. When I go to the preview it says "The following classes could not be found: com.google.Ads.AdView

Comment: And I have the Google Play Services added as a library and copied the play services.jar into my lib folder

Comment: I faced the same initially..Then You have to add GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar in your libs folder ...it will solve the issue

Comment: So I did that and now its saying "The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.google.ads.AdView"   When click Open Class its saying that the source for AdView.class could not be found.

Comment: Have you added GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar in your java buildpath ??